# How to get file path from symlink?

Tags: php, linux

How can i get information via php or bash to what file referencing a symlink in linux?

Comment: In bash an `ls -l` gives you target listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SYMPATH` is a symlink to `REALPATH`, then

```
readlink SYMPATH
```

returns `REALPATH`

Answer (score 4):

Example from [`SplFileInfo::getLinkTarget`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getlinktarget.php)

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('/Users/bbieber/workspace');
if ($info->isLink()) {
    var_dump($info->getLinkTarget());
    // gives string(19) "Documents/workspace"
    var_dump($info->getRealPath());   
    // gives string(34) "/Users/bbieber/Documents/workspace"
}
```

Comment: `SplFileInfo::isLink`/`getLinkTarget` are only used for soft links. For hard links, they just appear as a regular file/directory: `isLink` will return `false`.

Comment: ok, i was wrong, i have hardlink, and none of this answers not working

Answer (score 2):

In php you can use the [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [readlink function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php) or the [readlink command](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=r/readlink).